# ¿Cómo dividir matemáticamente dos consultas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Yo tengo dos consultas distintas:

Esta:

```
select SUM(calidadProducto) from calidad cal where cal.codigo = 50;
```

que me devolverá el valor 11.

Y esta:

```
select COUNT(calidadProducto) from calidad cal where cal.codigo = 50;
```

que me devolverá el valor 4.

Yo lo que necesito es dividir (matemáticamente hablando) las consultas.
Y así obtener el resultado: 2.75 o 3 si devuelve como entero.
Por que lo que yo tengo es la suma total y las cantidades, falta hacer esa división para obtener el promedio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cualquier columna puede ser el resultado de dos columnas. Como lo que tenes ahi tiene la misma condicion de `where`, entonces se puede reducir a una columna:

```
select SUM(calidadProducto)/COUNT(calidadProducto) as RESULTADO
from calidad cal where cal.codigo = 50;
```

Ojo, esto no quiere decir que la consulta sea optima ni rapida, pero soluciona tu problema

Answer (score 2):

Sé que es tarde para responder tu pregunta pero le puede servir a alguien más, puedes sólo poner:

```
select AVG(calidadProducto) as Promedio from calidad cal where cal.codigo = 50
```

y te dará el promedio de la columna